# Shit SE Says - Stack Exchange chat stars out of context

Tags: app

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: Shit SE Says]

### About

The first thing you need to know is that it took me about 5 minutes of refreshing that the app to find two screenshots that were Safe For Work (and as a bonus, contained no swearing). So this app isn't for those who are easily offended.

This app takes all of the starred messages from a bunch of different chat rooms (not all of them, but the most active), and shows them totally out of context. But fear not, if you want to see the context, there's a nice big button to do so. Except it's not always so helpful.

#### License

N/A

#### Access

[http://яѱ.com/shitsesays/](http://xn--41a2e.com/shitsesays/)

#### Platform

Any decent browser.

### Contact

Leave some feedback in this question.

Comment: Nice. It even came up with a few I thought worthwhile enough to put in the quote pool for [Q4TD](http://q4td.blogspot.com).

Comment: Could you add functionality to choose which room(s) to look in? I don't want to see any of the crap those guys natter on about in The Comms Room. ;-)

Comment: The thought had crossed my mind - but I haven't done any work on this since 14th December 2012 (i.e. the day I published it here). If I find myself with nothing to do one night I might throw some more features in.

Comment: NEEDZ MOAR +1!!

Comment: Being able to view only room 11 stars would be neat...

Comment: MarkHenderson - just a quick bump. Do you think @Iszi's functionality request can be implemented? Would be useful (and is desired) on a range of sites.